# Linq Query to Count Properties per value

Tags: c#, linq

I have 1 list of objects that I want to filter to populate another list of different objects.

In the first list named "SelectedAssets" I have 2 properties that I m interested in. The name of the properties are "AdminOperator" and the "Identifier" they re both of type string.

The goal is to populate the second list named "SystemsPerPlatform" with the properties "Name" (type string) and "TotalSystems" (type int).

So I wan to count the number of "Identifier" that each "AdminOperator" has in the first list named "SelectedAssets", then populate the results to the second list named "SystemsPerPlatform". The results in the second list should be similar to 
Name = "SomeUniqueName1", TotalSystems = 300
Name = "SomeUniqueName2", TotalSystems = 200

And so on....
The names must not repeat and each name should have the correspondent TotalSystems count that refer to each "Identifier" that they have in their name.

So far I did:

```
SystemsPerPlatform.Clear();

            var results = SelectedAssets.GroupBy(a => a.AdminOperator)
                .Select(y => new PlatformStats { Name = y.Key, TotalSystems = y.Sum(x => x.Identifier.Count())})
                .ToList();

            results.ForEach(x=>
            {
                SystemsPerPlatform.Add(x);
            });
```

But this is not working, the x.Identifier.Count() is counting the chars and not each instance that each Name = y.Key has associated with it.

Can you help?

Comment: Have you tried just doing `TotalSystems = y.Count()`?

Comment: Thank you that worked fine, because this is a very large list how can I restrict the top 30 results (the top 30 that have the most systes associated with) so my ui does not block. Thank uyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 var assets = SelectedAssets.GroupBy(a => a.AdminOperator)
 .Select
 (
    g => new PlatformStats()
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        TotalSystems = g.Count()
    }
 ).OrderByDescending(g => g.TotalSystems)
 .Take(30);

 foreach (var asset in assets)
 {
      SystemsPerPlatform.Add(asset);
 }
```

Comment: That should work, bu I made a mistake, the SystemsPerPlatform is an Observable collection and does not support AddRange. I m using it with WPF

Comment: because this is a very large list how can I restrict the top 30 results (the top 30 that have the most systes associated with) so my ui does not block.

Comment: Take another look. I updated my answer to address your concerns... :-)